# How choose a proper ARIMA model?

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-selection

I am doing my project on forecasting and I have to use the ARIMA for it.
I have tried but still unable to identify which ARIMA model is appropriate for my data set?
Either to use ARIMA or SARIMA.

Here is the ACF:

[image: ACF]

And the PACF:  [image: PACF]

Comment: I have seen acf's like this before and as I remember the data had fixed seasonal effects (monthly dummies). Please post your data and I will try and help further.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Actually the dataset is quite large and I was not able to upload it. Can I have your email, please.

Comment: dave@autobox.com

Comment: I have shared the data with you via email. Please have a look.
I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Did you follow the steps I took to identify the model ?

Answer (score 0):

In general the model building process is here https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf . In specific here is the actual data (99 monthly values) [image] . The acf of the original data is here [image]

After seasonal differencing the acf/pcf is here [image]
suggesting the following model [image]

As part of the model identification process we use the CHOW test to test the hypothesis that the model parameters are invariant over time. Not so in this case … and decidedly not so visually .[image] suggesting a partitioning of the data at or about period 58 thus 1-57 has been found to differ from 58-99 . This apect of modelling is often ( if not always !) overlooked in modelling chronological data but I find is quite prevalent in data.

This specific form of non-stationarity in the data would probably cause havoc AND confusion with simple AIC based model detection algorithms .

Analyzing the most recent 42 values  we find the following model. [image] suggesting a pulse at the last point .

The residuals from this model have an acf suggesting sufficiency [image] and plotted here [image]

The plot of the Actual/Fit and Forecast from this tour de force is here [image] showing forecasts for the next 36 periods on the premis that the actual value at the ultimate data point is a pulse (one-time aberration)

I show here the result of 1000 simultions the probability density function for the forecast interval for 1 period out via bootstrapping [image]

THis was all done AUTOMATICALLY using AUTOBOX wich I have helped to develop.

[image]